# auto, try-catch, and scopes

Tags: scope, try-catch, auto

I have a piece of code like this:

```
auto theval = myfunc();

dosomething(theval);
```

Now, I want to wrap the first part in a `try/catch` block:

```
try {
  auto theval = myfunc();
} catch (const std::exception& ex){
  // do some error handling
}
dosomething(theval);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because `theval` is inside the `try` scope.

The conventional way to solve this would be to just move the declaration outside the scope like this:

```
auto theval;
try {
  theval = myfunc();
} catch (const std::exception& ex){
  // do some error handling
}
dosomething(theval);
```

But this doesn't work either, because `auto` can't be used without an initialization.

Is there a way in which I can solve this without having to explicitly use the return type of `myfunc` and without having to move the call to `dosomething` inside the `try` block?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `decltype` like this:

```
decltype(myfunc()) theval;
try {
  theval = myfunc();
} catch (const std::exception& ex){
  // do some error handling
}
dosomething(theval);
```

perhaps augmented with `std::remove_reference<...>::type` to avoid issues with functions returning references.